# Proper way of initializing Reveal modals in Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I've recently implemented a few modals using Foundation 6 Reveal module. I set up every thing according to the docs with data-open, data-reveal attributes etc. I used:

```js
var reveal = new Foundation.Reveal($(".reveal"))
```

This seemed to work until I had two diffrent modals in the same page, so now I have to initialize like this for everything to work properly (in a doc-ready):

```js
 $(".reveal").each(function() {
        var r = new Foundation.Reveal($(this));
});
```

Is this the correct way of doing it, or am I missing something?

Comment: normally the first should work for multiple items

Comment: Well it does not. When i look at the implementation of Reveal, it accepts an "element" argument (and optional options argument). Note element not elements.

Comment: If you can use the whole foundation.js then simply calling **$(document).foundation();** should work - see example [here](http://codepen.io/dex3844/pen/VmmrYY?editors=1010) *assuming you are using foundation 6*